# android/java multitouch, whats & in this case and whats >>?

Tags: java, android, multi-touch, masking

I'm new too the android world, and quite new too Java as well, but with a few years as a dot-net:er and a few school points in Java for a few years ago I'm not totally behind :).. but I still don't really get what the '&' and the '>>' actually does in the following two lines.. could anyone please explain it..

```
int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
```

If I understand the first line correct, the event.getAction() returns an int with a bunch of information, but since we only are interested of which action that fired we add the '& MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK' to sort of "parse" out that bit.. am I right or am I totally wrong?

The 2:nd line I have no idea what the '>>' is used for.. so please explain :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and is there any reason why event.getAction returns more then not just which action that actually was fired?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: thanks that explains it abit more :), still seems wierd to me to not simply return the action directly at event.getAction :/.. or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

[`getAction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getAction%28%29) used to (in older versions of Android) just return the very basic up, down, hover (etc.) action. This allowed you to do things like `event.getAction() == ...` to find out if it was a specific kind of action. However, touch events got more complicated with the introduction of multitouch. Now, along with the action, pointer information is stored in the "action" as well. Before you ask: Yes, they could have made it two different methods, but is it not just easier to be able to have the entirety of the action's information in one?

As shown in [@millimoose's link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) in the JavaDocs, `&` will keep just the bits that match (`a & b == 1` for two bits `a` and `b` if and only if `a == b == 1`). You may also want to look at [the basics of bit flags and fields](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/BitFlags.htm), which are integers that use their bits to represent various states.

So, when you call `& MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK`, it will keep only those bits which match [`ACTION_MASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MASK)'s bits (`11111111`, or the rightmost 8 bits). This is where the action is stored (notice that all action integer values are less than 255--the rightmost 8 bits).

The next line takes the second set of 8 bits (from the right, they are the 8th to 15th bits, inclusive), then shifts them right by 8, so that `1 0000 0000` (spaces added for demonstration) becomes `1`. (This operator, the right shift, also is explained in the JavaDoc link.)

So let's say the event is `ACTION_UP` and the pointer index is 6, which gives us information on the event and on the pointer. That would be represented as `(6 << ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT) | ACTION_UP`, or `110 0000 0001`. In this case,

- the value of `event.getAction()` is equal to `110 0000 0001`;
- your `action` variable is equal to `0000 0001` (you can ignore the leading 0s, of course); and
- your `pointerIndex` variable is equal to `110` (or `6` in decimal).

Keep in mind, on APIs 8 and higher, you have access to [`getActionMasked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionMasked%28%29), which gets you the `action` variable you've used above.